# MATLAB: Find locations of multiple characters inside string

Tags: string, matlab, find, location

How can I find the locations of certains characters within a string. This is my attempt:

```
Example = "Hello, this is Tom. I wonder, should I go run?";
SearchedCharacters = {'.','!',',','?'};
%Plan one
Locations = strfind(Example, SearchedCharacters);
%Plan two
Locations = cellfun(@(s)find(~cellfun('isempty',strfind(C,s))),SearchedCharacters,'uni',0);
```

Both of my plans give errors.

Finally. Having the locations of the characters within the string, I would like to determine, the second last character of interest in the string. In this case it would be ","(Just after the word "wonder"), in location = 29.

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ismember](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.htm) and [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).

Find the second last location:

```
Example = 'Hello, this is Tom. I wonder, should I go run?' ;
SearchedCharacters = '.!,?' ;
idx = ismember (Example, SearchedCharacters);
Loc = find (idx, 2, 'last');
if numel (Loc) < 2
    error ('the requested character cannot be found')
end
SecondLast = Loc (1);
```

Find all locations:

```
Locations = find (idx);
```